# Call parent constructor with private members in parent class

Tags: c++, oop

It is possible to call the parent constructor having the members of it in private?
I know that with protected this works, but I prefer to use private, is there any way to solve this?

```
class Product {

    std::string id;
    std::string description;
    double rateIVA;

public:
    Product(std::string id, std::string description, double rateIVA);
    ~Product();

    // Abstract Methods / Pure Virtual Methods
    virtual double getIVAValue() = 0;
    virtual double getSaleValue() = 0;

    // Virtual Method
    virtual void print() const;

    // Setters & Getters
    void setId(std::string id);
    std::string getId() const;
    void setDescription(std::string description);
    std::string getDescription() const;
    void setRateIVA(double rateIVA);


    double getRateIVA() const;
};

class FixedPriceProduct : protected Product {

    double price;

    public:
        FixedPriceProduct();
            FixedPriceProduct(double price); // Implement here
        ~FixedPriceProduct();

        double getIVAValue();
        double getSaleValue();

        virtual void print() const;
};
```

Comment: I don´t understand the problem. You have a `Product(std::string id, std::string description, double rateIVA);`, this fills the three member variables of product (at least I think it does), and it is public. Just call it in the child constructor´s init list? (The child constructor needs some more params to get values for the parent, but there is no problem with private)

Comment: private inheritance will also work, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042921/i-inherited-a-constructor-using-private-why-am-i-still-be-able-to-access-it-fro

Comment: @deviantfan: what do you mean? the link is not about private constructor.

Comment: @swang Ah sorry, don´t know what I read there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent's constructor is `public` or `protected`, then there is no problem with calling it, even if the members it is initializing are private. Although it is not clear how your example will initialize the parent, so I'll just write something simpler to make things clearer:

```
class Parent {
    int mem_;

public:
    Parent(int mem) : mem_(mem) { }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(int mem) : Parent(mem) { }
};
```

The above example will work, no problem. The catch is that if you want to modify the `mem_` member using the `Child` class, you can only do so using the `public` and `protected` accessor methods that the `Parent` class provides.

Comment: Thank you! It's true it works, as you said, even if the members it is initializing are private the parent's constructor is public so you can access  it.

Comment: No problem. Since you are a new user, I should probably mention that you can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check-mark under the number to the left of the answer, so that others may benefit from the presented answer